# How to turn off the time selection in the bootstrap datepicker?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I've embed a bootstrap datepicker from http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker/demo.php

I want only the date and month and year to be displayed. But in this plugin I've date,month,year, and time. How do I remove only the time selection from this datepicker?

Comment: It would be helpful for you to include a small section of the code you're using.

Comment: This is the script that I'm using

<script>
      
$('.calender').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
      </script>

Comment: Don't forget to click the check mark if someone has successfully solved your problem!

Answer (score 1):

Use [DatePicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) instead of DateTimePicker.

Answer (score 0):

I use a different datetime picker, and have had great success with it. [Bootstrap 3 Date/Time Picker](https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker).  It uses [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and allows for all sorts of date/time formatting options.  It is also more accessible, and allows for scrolling through the calendar and time option using a keyboard.

Using the plugin I suggested, the format for just the date would be:

```
$('.formDate').datetimepicker({
    format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
});
```